# Python - Read file content as binary without its metadata

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 identical files but they have different metadata (i.e. last modified date)
Is there a way to read the files as binary without their metadata to be able to compare them?

Here is an example for the 2 different values between file1 and file2, the rest of the 2 files content is identical:

1. b'[<100b873bbc7f45a090b65bb840825f2d><100b873bbc7f45a090b65bb840825f2d>]'
2. b"(D:20210909223436-02'00')"

Here is the code from which I got these different values (it is not the perfect code):

```
with open(file_path1,'rb') as file:
        content1= file.read()   

with open(file_path2,'rb') as file:
        content2= file.read()

diff= set(content1.split())- set(content2.split()))
print(diff)
```

In the beginning I was expecting that there will no be difference between the 2 files since they are 2 PDF files with the exact content

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you mean by metadata or how you obtained the items in your post.  Could you post some code to clarify what you mean?

Comment: The metadata returned by a call like `stat` is independent of the binary contents of the file that you'd get with `open(x, 'rb').read()`.

Comment: @djones I added sample code on how I got these  2 different values

Comment: They're not identical if the differing metadata is stored in the file.

Comment: You need a proper PDF parser if you need to dig into the contents of the files like this.

Comment: @chepner I was searching for a quick hack to compare both files instead of OCRing both files which will take more time

Comment: @chepner  and if both files are identical, I can skip the OCR step (as the document was not updated since the last OCR event)

Comment: Is this a physical document being scanned? You're unlikely to get it aligned just right to get an identical scan (ignoring any random noise in the scanning process that will produce negligible differences).